# How to pick active color id of list of color id's available

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i want to pick color id of active color like suppose i have three colors yellow, blue, red. By default the first color is yellow so i get the color id of  yellow by using "input type hidden". but when we click on the blue color then the active color will be  blue so i needed color id of blue and if i click on red then color id of red. i need a active color identifier t get the id of that active coloe.  here is my code

```
 <p class="product-color"> Color :                     
  <?php foreach($avlcolers as $colors){ ?>
   <button type="button" title="<?php echo $colors['color_name']; ?>" id="btn2" onclick="variationchange(<?php echo $colors['color_id'] ; ?>)" style="background:<?php echo $colors['color_value']; ?>;padding:12px;border: 1px solid #ccc;border-radius: 50%;border:1px solid #ccc; color: white; width: 40px; height:40px;" value="5" class="color-btn"></button>
   <?php    } ?>                            
 </p>
```

when i try to get color_id like using below code in above code

```
 <input type="hidden" id="color_id" value="<?php echo $colors['color_id'] ; ?>" >
```

i am getting color_id of only first color.
Is there any way to get color_id of current color.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery data-id attribute as shown:

```
<p class="product-color"> Color :                     
  <?php foreach($avlcolers as $colors){ ?>
   <button type="button" title="<?php echo $colors['color_name']; ?>" class="btn-colors" data-id="<?php echo $colors['color_id'];?>" style="background:<?php echo $colors['color_value']; ?>;padding:12px;border: 1px solid #ccc;border-radius: 50%;border:1px solid #ccc; color: white; width: 40px; height:40px;" value="5" class="color-btn"></button>
   <?php    } ?>                            
 </p>
```

Then add a button click event for the color buttons(based on class)

```
<script>
  $('.btn-colors').click(function(){
       var colorID = (this).attr('data-id');
       // then set the value of colo id field to the above id
       ("#color_id").val(colorID);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: This is not working. Actually we have to identify active button first. Like by default first color (yellow) is active so we get first color id, then we click on a color suppose red then the active color is red we should have to get red color id and so on for multiple colors. Your code will only give first color id. Anyway thanks for the effort sir.